# ConfigurationProperties class doesn't load information from native image

Tags: resources, micronaut, graalvm, configurationproperties

I'm working with Micronaut GraalVM application, I've created a class to load information from application.yml using **@ConfigurationProperties**, it works when I run my jar application, then I built a native image with it, but my configuration properties class doesn't load any information,I tried adding my configuration properties class in --initialize-at-build-time but this neither worked, this is my code:

application.yml

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: mngraalvm
team:
  name: 'Steelers'
  color: 'Black'
  player-names:
    - 'Mason Rudolph'
    - 'James Connor'
```

Engine.java

```
package com.msc.configurationprop;

public interface Engine {
    String getName();
    String getColor();
}
```

EngineConfig.java

```
package com.msc.configurationprop;

import io.micronaut.context.annotation.ConfigurationProperties;

import java.util.List;

@ConfigurationProperties("team")
class EngineConfig {
    private String name;
    private String color;
    private List<String> playerNames;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public List<String> getPlayerNames() {
        return playerNames;
    }

    public void setPlayerNames(List<String> playerNames) {
        this.playerNames = playerNames;
    }

}
```

EngineImpl.java

```
package com.msc.configurationprop;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class EngineImpl implements Engine {
    private final EngineConfig config;

    public EngineImpl(EngineConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public final EngineConfig getConfig() {
        return config;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return config.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColor() {
        return config.getColor();
    }
}
```

HomeController.java

```
@Controller("/home")
public class HomeController {
  private final EngineImpl engineimpml;

  @Get("/team")
  public EngineImpl team() {
      return this.engineimpml;
  }

  public HomeController(@Nullable EngineImpl engineimpml) {
      this.engineimpml = engineimpml;
  }
}
```

Do I need to inject my EngineImpl class in Application.java or another configuration?
Thanks.

Comment: which micronaut version are you using?